# cxBarEditItem will not accept adding items

Tags: delphi, devexpress

My cxBarEditItem1 has properties : combobox.

However when I begin to write :

> cxBarEditItem1.Properties.Items.Add ...

Delphi shows me it's an error. It seems 'items' do not exist.

What am I doing wrong ? How can I fill it ?

Comment: why is it that some people understand the question and some people don't is a mystery.How comes a guy like Uli gives the right answer while others struggle with the question itself. Its perfectly well asked and people who know what a cxBarEditItem is know what the asker is having trouble with. And how comes this question is off topic is beyond me.

Comment: That this is a perfectly normal question and that has been asked before can be seen on devexpress support center : https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q32066.

Comment: @user763539: The DevEx SC is **support** while SO is a Q&A site which expects higher quality questions. (Sometimes __too__ high for my taste. :-))

Comment: @Uli Gerhardt Is not this site meant to be support for the programmers in their quest for knowledge  ? Experts as well as the beginners ? If not, what exactly are we trying to accomplish here ? More experienced programmers should know better that to put this question on hold.

Comment: The OP could improve the question, then I guess it might be re-opened. Things like mentioning the type of cxBarEditItem1 etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler doesn't know that `cxBarEditItem1.Properties` refers to a ComboBox at runtime. You have to cast to tell it:

```
Assert(cxBarEditItem1.Properties is TcxComboBoxProperties);
TcxComboBoxProperties(cxBarEditItem1.Properties).Items.Add('Hello');
```

Comment: actually you could do without the first line.

Comment: @user763539: Of course. One could do without **any** `Assert`. But one doesn't want to. :-)

Comment: @Uli Gerhardt I'm glad you could answer this quesion for him Uli, I was afraid the question would be shut down by the "Not a good enough question" police before someone could get a word in edgewise!

Comment: @Nat Thank's Nat !

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the DevExpress Expressbar controls... But I have downloaded the help file for the components. I can recommend the help, it's very useful.

From what I can see, you really want to put a TcxBarCombo on your bar, which does have an items property.

I *think* you have dropped a non-ribbon style Combo on to your ribbon, which may be a separate component on your form... Maybe try clicking on the combo and seeing what the component name is in the object inspector, then use that name to add items to the control.

Comment: Small edit: a bar combo is a `TdxBarCombo` (in DevExpress 16). And a normal `TcxComboBox` _can_ be placed on a bar, using a `TdxBarControlContainerItem`, this will however keep the normal control somewhere else in the form at designtime. The barcontrolcontainer will the show text along the lines of `The place for [name of combobox]`